# Input Issues when using do-while loop

Tags: c#

Whenever input is outside of range 1-4 its supposed to throw an Invalid entry text and ask for another input, however when you type in another input, the program error's out and doesn't continue. I'm not sure where I am going wrong. I am using C# and this is an assignment that requires me to use the do while loop for this section.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Write("Enter a salespersons name: ");
  string salesPerson = ReadLine();

  int intItem;
  int intQuantity;
  double item1 = 239.99;
  double item2 = 129.75;
  double item3 = 99.95;
  double item4 = 350.89;
  double dblItemSales;
  double dblTotalSales;

  do
  {
    Write("Enter an item number between 1 and 4 or -1 to quit: ");
    intItem = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

    if ( intItem < 1 || intItem > 4 )
    {
      WriteLine("Invalid Entry");
      Write("Enter an item number between 1 and 4 or -1 to quit: ");
      intItem = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
    }
    else if ( intItem == -1 )
    {
      WriteLine("Salesperson " + salesPerson + " sold a total of ");
      break;
    }
    else
      Write("Enter the quantity sold: ");

    intQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
  } 
  while ( intItem != -1 );

  WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue.");
  ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Since `-1 < 1` it is the very first brunch `if ( intItem < 1 || intItem > 4 )` which runs.

Comment: make sure you use try catch when trying to parse data too intItem = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

Comment: Btw, whenever you are dealing with user entered data, you need to assume the user will mess up. Instead of using `Convert.ToInt32` use `int.TryParse`. That way if some types `one` instead of `1`, you can easily handle things without having to catch an exception

Comment: @Nikki9696 System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' This happens at the line of intQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

Comment: yeah you have a couple of other issues there, one pointed out by Dmitry and also you'd want to tryparse and also break after that invalid input

Answer (score 0):

You can try such thing, depending of what you want to do with quantities entered hence I put something for the sample:

```
bool isValid;
do
{
  Console.Write("Enter an item number between 1 and 4 or -1 to end: ");
  int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out intItem);
  if ( intItem == -1 ) break;
  if ( intItem < 1 || intItem > 4 )
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry: try again, please.");
    continue;
  }
  dblItemSales++;
  do
  {
    Console.Write("Enter the quantity sold: ");
    isValid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out intQuantity) && intQuantity >= 0;
    if ( !isValid )
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry: try again, please.");
  }
  while ( !isValid );
  dblTotalSales += intQuantity;
}
while ( true );

Console.WriteLine($"Sales person {salesPerson} sold a total of {dblTotalSales}" +
                  $" for {dblItemSales} items");

Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue.");
```

We use `TryParse` to ensure that a number is entered else it is 0 and the method rertuens false.

Answer (score 0):

Since `-1 < 1` it is the very *first* branch

```
 if ( intItem < 1 || intItem > 4 )  // true when intItem == -1 
 {
     ...
 }
 else if ( intItem == -1 )         // this branch will never be executed
```

which runs. Put it like this:

```
 while (true) { // keep looping until explicit quit
   Write("Enter an item number between 1 and 4 or -1 to quit: ");

   if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var intItem)) // what if user put "bla-bla-bla"? 
     Write("Syntax error. Integer 1..4 expected");
   else if (intItem == -1) {                       // quit
     WriteLine("Salesperson " + salesPerson + " sold a total of ");
     break; 
   } 
   else if (intItem < 1 || intItem > 4) {         // invalid range 
     WriteLine("Invalid Entry");
     Write("Enter an item number between 1 and 4 or -1 to quit:");
   }
   else {                                         // main routine 
     // intItem is integer in 1..4 range
     Write("Enter the quantity sold: ");

     //TODO: put relevant code here  
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Write("Enter a salespersons name: ");
        string salesPerson = ReadLine();

        int intItem;
        int intQuantity;
        double item1 = 239.99;
        double item2 = 129.75;
        double item3 = 99.95;
        double item4 = 350.89;
        double dblItemSales;
        double dblTotalSales;

        do
        {
            Write("Enter an item number between 1 and 4 or -1 to quit: ");
            if (Int32.TryParse(ReadLine(), out intItem))
            {
                if (intItem == -1)
                {
                    WriteLine("Salesperson " + salesPerson + " sold a total of ");
                    break;
                }
                else if (intItem < 1 || intItem > 4)
                {
                    WriteLine("Invalid Entry");
                }
                else
                {
                    Write("Enter the quantity sold: ");
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(ReadLine(), out intQuantity))
                    {
                        intQuantity = 0; // or whatever
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while (intItem != -1);

        WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue.");
        ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In case you don't want to change the current code. Short fix:**

1. Move this `intQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` line inside the else statement.
2. Delete this codes inside if statement:
   `Write("Enter an item number between 1 and 4 or -1 to quit: ");` 
   `intItem = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());`

It should be look like this:

```
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter an item number between 1 and 4 or -1 to quit:");
        intItem = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (intItem< 1 || intItem> 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Entry");
        }
        else if (intItem == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Salesperson " + salesPerson + " sold a total of ");
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the quantity sold: ");
            intQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
                

    }
    while (intItem != -1);

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue.");
    Console.ReadLine();
```